Get data connection name using IronPython in Spotfire
I have been searching the API and the web for getting the data connection name programmatically within an IronPython script. You can find the data connection information, which includes the name, in Spotfire here:

Data > Data Table Properties > Source Information

This is after copying to clipboard:
1. Imported data table from data connection.
    Connection name: CONNECTION NAME HERE
    Path to connection in library: PATH TO CONNECTION
    View name: VIEW
    Connection type: Google BigQuery
    On-demand settings
        Column to filter by: ---
            Expression: ---
            Limited by active filtering scheme: Yes
            Limited by: (None)
        Update behavior: Manual
        Caching allowed: Yes
    Data loaded at: 02-Aug-2024 08:32

Is there a way to extract the 'Connection name' from this information? Or anywhere else the connection name is stored...

The dxp in this community article kind of works: it asks for some connections details but you can skip them.
https://community.spotfire.com/articles/spotfire/how-to-use-ironpython-in-spotfire-to-get-the-datatable-source-information/

you need to trust the script

you need to use an empty text area as input parameter (otherwise the button gets overwritten)

you need to change line 25 like this (at least if worked when I tried):
if found.First is not None: writeHtml(tbl.Name,type(t).__name__,found.First.Path)


